# How to store of array of files and fields in mysql database using php

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I want to know how the arrays from the following HTML and Javascript can be stored in a Mysql database with each field added to the following columns inside MYSQL Database: title, category, pdfname(the name of the files being sent from the HTML) and the files from the HTML being stored on a directory named "pdffile" on the server For each recordset added by the Javascript.

Below is the JAVASCRIPT code:

```js
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
function addRow(tableID) {
 var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
 var rowCount = table.rows.length;
 if(rowCount < 10){                            // limit the user from creating fields more than your limits
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
  var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
  for(var i=0; i <colCount; i++) {
   var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
   newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
  }
 }else{
   alert("Maximum Number of Books is 10");
      
 }
}

function deleteRow(tableID) {
 var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
 var rowCount = table.rows.length;
 for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
  var row = table.rows[i];
  var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
  if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
   if(rowCount <= 1) {               // limit the user from removing all the fields
    alert("Cannot Remove all the Books.");
    break;
   }
   table.deleteRow(i);
   rowCount--;
   i--;
  }
 }
}
</SCRIPT>
```

```html
</HEAD>
    <div style="border:auto solid 1px; font-size:15px; background-color:red; width:100%;">
    <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="pdf_form" method="post" name="pdf_form">

     
      <table id="dataTable" class="form" border="1">
      <tbody>
     <p>
     <td >
      <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" checked="checked" />
     </td>
     <td>
     <label for="title">Title of PDF</label>
     <input type="text" id="title" name="title[]">

     
     <td>
     <label for="pdffile">PDF supported. 2MB Maximum)</label>
     <input type="file" id="pdffile" name="pdffile[]">
     
     </td>
     
     <td>
     <label for="category">Category</label>
     <select id="category" name="category[]"> 
        <option>Science</option>
        <option>Technology</option>
        <option>Biblical</option>
        <option>Business</option>
        <option>Medical</option>
        <option>Engineering</option>
        <option>World</option>
     </select>
     </td>
     
     </p>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>


    <p> 
      <input type="button" value="Add PDF" onClick="addRow('dataTable')" /> 
      <input id="button" name="submit" type="submit" value="Save PDF(s)" />
      
      <p>(All actions apply only to entries with check marked check boxes only.)</p>
    </p>
    </form>
    </div>

    //PHP for Upload

    <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
   include("session.php");
   session_start();
   
   if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") { 
      
   $pdffile = $_FILES['pdffile']['name'];
   $pdffile_name = $_POST['pdffile'];
   // Get text
   $pdffile_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['pdffile_name']);

   // image file directory
   $target = "books/".basename($pdfstore);  
      
$item_title = $_POST['title'];
$item_category = $_POST['category'];
$item_pdfname_name = $_POST['pdfname_name'];

foreach ($_FILES as $pdfname)

  if (move_uploaded_files($pdffile['tmp_name'], 'pdfstorage/' . $file['pdffile']))

for($count = 0; $count<count($item_title); $count++){

  $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$item_title[$count]);
  $category = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$item_category[$count]);
  $pdfname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $item_pdfname[$count]);
  
 {
    


  $sql = "INSERT INTO pdftable (title, category, pdfname) VALUES('$title', '$category', '$pdfname')";
}
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pdffile']['tmp_name'], $target));

  if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "<div style='border:auto solid 1px; font-size:15px; color:green; background-color:auto; width:100%;'> PDF with Title $title Added Successfully. </div>";
  }
  else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $con->error;
  };
};
};
?>
```

Each time, the fields "Category[]" and "Title[]" are added to the database, but, the files are not moved to the "pdfstorage" folder on the server and the file names are not added to the database to. I need the MYSQL code for successfully adding the files and the fields to the database. Help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: @Sushank Pokharel Please, I need someone to help with this. Thanks

Comment: As a start, you declared pdffile in your html as an array, however you are accessing it as a variable: name="pdffile[]" makes the file available at $_FILES['pdffile']['name'][0]. Not $_FILES['pdffile']['name'].  Everything in your loop should reference $_FILES['pdffile'][<name>][$count], for example. There is lots that would need to be revised. I'll see if I can come back with more.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some working php code. Please note that you have lots of security issues with your code. Using raw $_POST data, not validating user input, filtering user input... See prepared statements and binding w/ mysqli as well. You'll want to make sure that a PDF is indeed a PDF file, for example.

Here is some working code for the file upload portion. I commented out the database query and escape string calls. I didn't want to setup the database. I was working with an upload directory ($target) "html" vs book/... for testing. I removed the included session.php call, because I didn't want to create that file. There are a few places you'll want to tweak my code. I turned on display_errors, for example too. Hope this helps. My html isn’t indented either, because I was scrambling to get something quickly to you. I remove some stray unneeded semicolons as well.

```
<html>
<head>
    <SCRIPT language="javascript">
function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    if(rowCount < 10){                            // limit the user from creating fields more than your limits
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
        for(var i=0; i <colCount; i++) {
            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
        }
    }else{
         alert("Maximum Number of Books is 10");
    }
}

function deleteRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
        var row = table.rows[i];
        var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
        if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
            if(rowCount <= 1) {               // limit the user from removing all the fields
                alert("Cannot Remove all the Books.");
                break;
            }
            table.deleteRow(i);
            rowCount--;
            i--;
        }
    }
}
</SCRIPT>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="border:auto solid 1px; font-size:15px; background-color:red; width:100%;">
    <form action="./test.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="pdf_form" method="post" name="pdf_form">


      <table id="dataTable" class="form" border="1">
      <tbody>
        <p>
        <td >
            <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" checked="checked" />
        </td>
        <td>
        <label for="title">Title of PDF</label>
        <input type="text" id="title" name="title[]">


        <td>
        <label for="pdffile">PDF supported. 2MB Maximum)</label>
        <input type="file" id="pdffile" name="pdffile[]">

        </td>

        <td>
        <label for="category">Category</label>
        <select id="category" name="category[]">
        <option value="Science">Science</option>
        <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
        </select>
        </td>

        </p>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
    <p>
      <input type="button" value="Add PDF" onClick="addRow('dataTable')" />
      <input id="button" name="submit" type="submit" value="Save PDF(s)" />

      <p>(All actions apply only to entries with check marked check boxes only.)</p>
    </p>
    </form>
    </div>
</td>
</p>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

session_start();

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // image file directory
    $target = __DIR__."/html/";

    foreach ($_FILES as $pdfname) {
        for ($count = 0; $count < count($_FILES['pdffile']['tmp_name']); $count++) {
            $item_title = $_POST['title'][$count];
            $item_category = $_POST['category'][$count];
            $pdffile = $_FILES['pdffile']['name'][$count];

            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pdffile']['tmp_name'][$count], $target.$pdffile)) {
                // Whatever you were going to do here....
            }

            //$sql = "INSERT INTO pdftable (title, category, pdfname) VALUES('$title', '$category', '$pdfname')";
            //$title = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $item_title);
            //$category = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $item_category);
            //$pdfname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $pdffile);
            //$pdffile_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['title'][$count]);


            /**if ($con->query($sql) === true) {
                echo "<div style='border:auto solid 1px; font-size:15px; color:green; background-color:auto; width:100%;'> PDF with Title $title Added Successfully. </div>";
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $con->error;
            };**/
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this.

Comment: Your approach partially works as it successfully moved the uploaded files to the intended folder. But, it only shows a character in each column

Comment: @SamolinaOne I didn’t adjust your query for you. I was focusing on the upload. You’d have to adjust your query variables, but you’d also want to use prepared statements.

Comment: Thanks. But, upload is not my problem, the problem is uploading the files created with two other fields created by the Javascript statement. I will appreciate if you can help on it. Thanks again.